# Автоматическое изменение состояния компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется код рандомно заполнящий поле двумя цветами. Массив при инициализации формирую методом `generateData`:

```js
const getStyle = style => Object.assign({}, style);

const universeStyle = length => ({
  position: "relative",
  width: `${length * 10}px`,
  height: `${length * 10}px`,
  fontSize: '0',
  border: "1px solid #222"
});

const cellStyle = item => ({
  background: `${item.color}`,
  display: "inline-block",
  boxSizing: "border-box",
  width: "10px",
  height: "10px",
  //border: "1px solid grey"
});

const Cell = ({ item }) => (
  <div x={item.x} y={item.y} style={getStyle(cellStyle(item))} />
);

class Universe extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.generateData(props.width)
    };
  }

  getColor(colors = ["white", "black"]) {
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }

  generateArray(width, pos) {
    return Array.from({ length: width }).map((item, index) => ({
      y: pos,
      x: index,
      color: this.getColor()
    }));
  }

  generateData(width) {
    return Array.from({ length: width }).map((item, index) =>
      this.generateArray(width, index)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={getStyle(universeStyle(this.props.width))}>
        {this.state.data.map(item => item.map(item => <Cell item={item} />))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Universe width={70} />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Какой метод компонента использовать, чтобы, например, раз в секунду, запускалось перестроение поля с новым массивом?

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение, укажите, пожалуйста недостатки

```js
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => 
      this.setState({
        data: this.generateData(this.props.width)  
      }), 1000)
  }
```

Comment: таймер надо сохранять в компоненте и очищать на willunmount, то память течет (когда компонент размунтится ваш интервальчик будет бегать хотя никому уже не нужен)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму спасибо, добавлю